# Sort hashtable containing arrays - Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I am trying to sort an hashtable in Powershell with the following structure :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjSX6.png

Each value of the hashtable is an array containing multiple elements.

I would like to sort the hashtable based on the value of second element of each array, is it possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an ordered dictionary, then enumerate all the key-value pairs in the existing hashtable, sort them by the desired value and then add them to your new ordered dictionary:

```
# Create ordered dictionary
$ordered = [ordered]@{}

# Sort KVPs by value at index 1 (that's the second element) of the array 
$hashtable.GetEnumerator() |Sort-Object { $_.Value[1] } |ForEach-Object {
    # Copy the KVP to the ordered dictionary in... order
    $ordered[$_.Key] = $_.Value
}
```

`$ordered` now contains the same entries as `$hashtable`, but sorted according to your criteria